# Select a year from a sql value which has a date value of xxxx-xx-xx

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linux

In my SQL table i have birthdates stores in the column `bday` as (for example) `1987-02-31`

I want to have a SELECT query that only chooses from the year, and ignores the month and day, such as :

```
SELECT FROM users WHERE bday=1987
```

is this possible to do with the dates stored this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the [`YEAR()` MySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year):

```
WHERE YEAR(bday)=1987
```

Comment: Might it be a better idea to use the range `BETWEEN '1987-01-01' AND '1987-12-31'`? I think that with a range, an index could be used but with a function, an index could not be used. I think.

Answer (score 1):

@soju's answer is correct if the field is a Date datatype, but...

You specifically said that your database has them stored as `1987-02-31`

To me this suggests that you might be dealing with a database that uses varchar or another text field to store what should be dates.

If this is the case, you can use the [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function.

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(bday, 1,4) = '1987'
```

Comment: okay, it is stored as a date so using the YEAR function would be the most efficient?

Comment: That depends on a few things.  I actually think a range would be more efficient (@Wiseguy's note on soju's answer).   I think the Date function is the simplest to deal with, but if you're looking purely at performance, I'd think the range(BETWEEN) would be better.  To know for sure, you could try both and time them.  Depending on th number of records, the difference may be negligible.  There's often a trade-off between performance and simplicity/readability.  Which route you go will be up to you.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL, if your bday is a date column (not a text one), you can use the year() function like this:

```
select * from users where year(bday)=1987;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FROM users WHERE bday LIKE '1987-%'
```